# Read large dataset Pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to read a dataset of 20gb. I've searched for a solution,I've tried:

```
   data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', chunksize=1000,usecols=fields)
   df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

but still getting a memory error when passing to concatenate. (I changed chunksize many time, still the same)

I have 16gb of RAM working at 3000mhz.

Any suggestions?

I am trying to import the data into a dataframe for a Data Analysis and manipulation the export it back. (Data need to be cleaned from nans and noisy data ).

Comment: do you really need the whole data set in memory or can you process it in chunks?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425826/4889267) may be related - take a read (it's for opening large excel files and it's suggested to use CSV)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas?rq=1 also what makes you believe that you can load a 20GB file when you only have 16GB of RAM?

Comment: @MaxU I've seen your solution but didn't get the "process" task

Comment: before concatenating, could you process / compact your dataset. i.e. get rid of extra columns, using a dictionary encoding, etc.

Comment: @hdatas, i'd suggest you to rephrase you question describing what do you want to achieve with those CSV files - there is a chance we will find a working solution ... ;-)

Comment: @EdChum I've seen this solution too but coun't implement it successfully

Comment: @MaxU I've added it at the end :)

Comment: Export it back with the new created columns

Comment: @hdatas, i don't think we can help you having that less information. Some "Data Analysis and manipulation" can be done in chunks some (like sorting, grouping, etc.) can't.

Comment: @MaxU yes I'll use groupby and fillna

Comment: @hdatas, I'd recommend you either to get more RAM or to consider using Dask DataFrame's or even Apache Spark Cluster (buying more memory should be cheaper ;)

Comment: @MaxU I'll report it back to my company and ask for ram :P

Comment: Look at this: http://pythondata.wpengine.com/working-large-csv-files-python/. Have you tried using the Dask framework?

Comment: @Mokshyam I haven't I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing exactly what you want/need to accomplish with the data does make this tricky - but most data manipulation can be done with SQL and so I would suggest using [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) as the data processing engine.

[sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) stores data on-disk and will circumvent the impossibility of reading 20Gb of data into 16Gb or RAM.

Also, read the documentation for [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

You will need something like (not tested):

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('out_Data.db')

data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', chunksize=1000, usecols=fields)

for data_chunk in data:
    data_chunk.to_sql(conn, if_exists='append')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM data GROUPBY variable1")
<<<perform data manipulation using SQL>>>
```

Bear in mind that you can't bring your data into a pandas data frame unless the operations that you perform dramatically reduce the memory footprint.

To convert back to .csv follow [Write to CSV from sqlite3 database in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827028/write-to-csv-from-sqlite3-database-in-python)

For better performance:

- Increase the chunk size to the maximum your system can handle
- sqlite3 CLI actually has methods for auto-importing .csv files that would be a lot quicker than going via python.